# How to run protractor from webapp?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I've some protractor tests (against angularApp) that I would like to run. To do that, i've created an user interface that prompts an user for the script file. Then I need, somehow, make protractor start and run the test.

What are my options to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi @user3550498 , How were you able to achieve this I am looking for similar functionality . your help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the file to your backend (and save it), which then executes the test as you normally would `protractor conf.js`.

If you don't have a backend that can run protractor via node, then you need to fork your own copy of Protractor, strip out any node APIs, and do something similar to what https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runnerCli.js is doing, but it will be messy.